# Blade does not accept variable

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

This is my code

```
var feetype="{{App\StudentFee::where('id', '2')->value('student_fee_type')}}";
console.log(feetype);
```

Works perfectly fine.
However when I try to modify it like so

```
var fee_type_id = 2;
var feetype="{{App\StudentFee::where('id', fee_type_id)->value('student_fee_type')}}";
console.log(feetype);
```

It throws the following error

```
Use of undefined constant fee_type_id - assumed 'fee_type_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot insert js variables into php scripts.

Comment: @RobBiermann is correct, you will need to pass that value from JS to your server (link/redirect/ajax etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is run server side.
After it is done the content it generated is download to the client side where you work with `javascript`

Therefore your javascript variables wont be accessible to `PHP` on the server.

There are workarounds to give `PHP` the variables to work with.
Here you can find an example of this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters.

You can for example append this to your route `/{fee_type_id}` and pass the variable at the end of requested url. In you can than add in your code

```js
var feetype="{{App\StudentFee::where('id', $fee_type_id)->value('student_fee_type')}}";
```

Provided you pass the variable to wherever you need it.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not escaped the phrase `fee_type_id` in quotes so it is used as a constant however that constant is undefined. You probably meant to pass in a variable `$fee_type_id`.

Really though, you should be passing what you need into the blade view instead of performing eloquent model db queries inside the view.